# Align columns in Bootstrap. The first tile needs to be large

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, umbraco

I want to create a group of tiles using Bootstrap 3. On the page load, I get a list of names from server and I do a foreach on the names to create a  grid. For now I have achieved the tiles all to be equal size. And it looks like this.

[image: I have achieved]

But what I really need is

[image: I really need]

The first tile needs to be col-6, the remaining col-6 need to be occupied by four of them, and then all the remaining will be col-3.

How could I do this dynamically when the data is been looped through?

This is my existing code, where the tiles are of equal size.

```
@foreach (var blogmaster in Model.Content.Children.Where(p => p.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("blog")))
{
    foreach (var blog in blogmaster.Children)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor"); height: 250px; margin-right: 5px">
                <h4 style="padding-top: 32px; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: 300;">@blog.Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: If i make it in php can you convert?

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski : Yes, I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NB: My Umbraco code may contain errors. But I hope I convey the idea that you can use.

### 1) You can improve your layout

1. Calculate the height of the large block considering the gap between two rows of small blocks.
2. You do not need nested blocks, because you have calculated the height of the large block and all the blocks are floated left.

Please check the layout:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.blog > div {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .blog > div {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
.blog > .col-md-3 > div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 250px; 
}
.blog > .col-md-6 > div {
  background: orange;
  height: 505px; /* = 2 * col-md-3 + padding-top */
}
.blog h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  padding-top: 32px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row blog">
    <div class='col-md-6'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>

    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2) If only the first block has to be large

```
@foreach (var blogmaster in Model.Content.Children.Where(p => p.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("blog"))) 
{
    var isFirst = true;

    foreach (var blog in blogmaster.Children) 
    {

        <div class="col-md-@(isFirst ? 6 : 3)">
            <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor");">
                <h4>@blog.Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        isFirst = false;
    }
}
```

### 3) If you need to repeat a large block

```
@foreach (var blogmaster in Model.Content.Children.Where(p => p.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("blog"))) 
{
    var i = 0;

    foreach (var blog in blogmaster.Children) 
    {

        <div class="col-md-@(i % 9 == 0 ? 6 : 3)">
            <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor");">
                <h4>@blog.Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        i++;
    }
}
```

### 4) If you need a large block on the right side too

Apply the `float: right` property to the second large block when the screen width becomes `992px` or more. I've defined a new special class `.pull-md-right` for this purpose. It's an analogue of [the `.pull-right` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats).

Please check new layout:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/fhvj58c5/)  •  [codepen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/kkEgdx)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.blog > div {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .blog > div {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  .pull-md-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
.blog > .col-md-3 > div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 250px; 
}
.blog > .col-md-6 > div {
  background: orange;
  height: 505px; /* = 2 * col-md-3 + padding-top */
}
.blog h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  padding-top: 32px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row blog">
    <div class='col-md-6'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>

    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>

    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-6 pull-md-right'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>

    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'><div><h4>@blog.Name</h4></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the code can be like this.

```
@foreach (var blogmaster in Model.Content.Children.Where(p => p.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("blog"))) 
{
    var i = 0;

    foreach (var blog in blogmaster.Children) 
    {

        if (i % 18 == 0)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
        }
        else if (i % 18 == 11)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        }
        else 
        {
            <div class="col-md-3">
        }

                <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor");">
                    <h4>@blog.Name</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel more comfortable with PHP and the questioner does not care, then how I solve this in PHP, generally, of course:

```
//Array declaration *ignore*
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
//Index Creation
$i=0;
//String to store results
$myResult = "";
foreach($array as $divs){
    if($i == 0 || $i>0 && $i<=4){
        $myResult .="<div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>";
    }else{
        $myResult .="<div class='col-md-3'>your content here</div>";
    }

    if($i==0){
        $myResult .="<div class='col-md-6'>";
    }elseif($i == 4){
        $myResult .= "</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Result:

```
<div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>your content here</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-3'>your content here</div>
<div class='col-md-3'>your content here</div>
<div class='col-md-3'>your content here</div>
<div class='col-md-3'>your content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by,

```
@foreach (var blog in blogmaster.Children)
{
    if (blog.name == "Product Path")
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor");  height: 500px; margin-right: 5px">
                <h4 style="padding-top: 32px; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: 300;">@blog.name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="background-color: #@blog.GetPropertyValue("backgroundColor");  height: 250px; margin-right: 5px">
                <h4 style="padding-top: 32px; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: 300;">@blog.name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Just get first item and assign its class as col-md-6 and others with col-md-3. Because I'm not having your dataset, I use my own simple dataset with same color. out put is like this,
[image]

Comment: The first 5 are col-6, wherein the second to fifth are encompassed by col-6.

Comment: Above code sample exactly produce what he request for. What ever it is the first item is col-6 and others are col-3. I can't understand what you suggesting ?

Comment: @Gabriel Tadra Mainginski look the image I added. my code sample produce that output.